# I-V data parsing in textfile

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files, streamreader

I am using a source meter which sweeps current and measures voltage and finally export all I-V data through rs232. 
I write them into a textfile with the format as following;
I1,V1,I2,V2,I3,V3...
I split all "commas" with the "split" function but I don't know how I can keep I-V couples into an array and then I want to calculate each resistance of each I-V by simple I/V calculation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Sample
{
public static void Main() {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myfilefile.txt")) {
        string line = null;
        while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) 
           {
            string[] values = line.Split(',');
           }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use `;` as a separator between the pairs?

Comment: Why not use MatLab? ;)

Comment: buy matlab for such a trivial tring..?

Comment: I always developed such applications on c#. Maybe next time I believe matlab easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j += 2) {
    double i = double.Parse(values[j]);
    double v = double.Parse(values[j+1]);
    double r = v / i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that you always have pairs (and thus an even number of elements in values) you can do this:

```
// your line 
string[] values = line.Split(',');
// my addition
for(int pair=0; pair<values.Length; pair=pair+2)
{
   string iValue = values[pair];
   string vValue = values[pair+1];

   Double i;
   Double v;
   bool iOk = Double.TryParse(iValue, out i);
   bool vOk = Double.TryParse(vValue, out v);
   if (iOk && vOk)
   {
       Double r = i/v;
       Console.WriteLine("{0} (R) = {1} (I) / {2} V ",r, i, v);
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} or {1} is not parseable", iValue, vValue);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you think this answer is the best fit for your question, please mark it as an answer...